# formula to check if the text from column A is the beginning or end of the text from column B

Tags: excel, comparison, excel-formula

i have values in column A and column B, where value in Row A is definitely part of Row B.
now i want to check if values in column A is the beginning of Column B, or the end of column B. Is there any way?

example of data:

```
Column A          Column B
Beijing           Beijing, China (A is the beginning of B)
Baslow            United Kingdom England Bakewell Baslow (A is the end of B)
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, that is possible:

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(A2,B2)),"Not part",IF(SEARCH(A2,B2)=1,"Beginning",IF(SEARCH(A2,B2)=LEN(B2)-LEN(A2)+1,"End","in the middle")))
```